# How to prove that 3 is divisor of two numbers and their sums?

Tags: solution-verification, natural-numbers

**Original question: Prove that if 3 is a divisor of two numbers, it is a divisor of their sum and their difference. Generalize this and prove that if d is a divisor of two numbers b1 and b2, then d is a divisor of b1 + b2 and of b1 -b2.** [*Question from Rational and Irrational numbers by Ivan Niven*]

I am new to proofs and I have limited methods to approach the problem.

Consider that if **num<sub>1</sub>** and **num<sub>2</sub>** which are exactly divisible by **3**, then

**num<sub>1</sub>** = **3 q<sub>1</sub>** [q1 is a quotient] and

**num<sub>2</sub>** = **3 q<sub>2</sub>**

Consider, if **3** divides exactly **num<sub>1</sub> + num<sub>2</sub>**

Then, (num<sub>1</sub> + num<sub>2</sub>)$\div$3

= (3 q<sub>1</sub> + 3 q<sub>2</sub>)$\div$3

= 3 (q<sub>1</sub> + q<sub>2</sub>)$\div$3

= q<sub>1</sub> + q<sub>2</sub>

= Q (Where Q = q<sub>1</sub> + q<sub>2</sub>  which in fact is integer)

So, can we address the first half of the question with this proof?

Comment: By definition, a number $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ divides a number $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ iff there exists $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $n = qd$. Now, if $3$ divides $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, then there exist $q_1,q_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $n_1 = 3q_1 $ and $n_2 = 3q_2 $; therefore $n_1 + n_2 = 3q_1+ 3q_2 = 3(q_1+q_2)$ and you can conclude... Obviously, you can generalize this argument to any divisor $d$.

Comment: The proof is in the wrong order - you can't say "Now, 3 divides exactly num1 + num2" before you've proven that. I also strongly advise not to use the symbol "/" (or a horizontal bar) to denote fractions when dealing with integer arithmetic. Instead, try to write your proof without any fractions at all.

Comment: @Stef Can you please provide your answer. So, that I can understand clearly what you are trying to say. I have done little changes. Sorry, I am new to proof :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change a few things in the second half of the proof. There are two things to take into account:

- Avoid using $/3$, $\div 3$ or $\frac{}{3}$. Your proof should use only integer arithmetics, no fractions.
- Add a few words to make sure that logic links between statements are more explicit; for instance, you can say "Now, let's use this to prove that 3 divides exactly $\operatorname{num}_1 + \operatorname{num}_2$" but not "Now, 3 divides exactly $\operatorname{num}_1 + \operatorname{num}_2$".

---

Let $\operatorname{num}_1$ and $\operatorname{num}_2$ be two integers divisible by $3$. We want to prove that their sum $\operatorname{num}_1 + \operatorname{num}_2$ is also divisible by $3$; *i.e.*, we want to prove that there exists an integer $Q$ such that $\operatorname{num}_1 + \operatorname{num}_2 = 3Q$.

By assumption, $\operatorname{num}_1$ and $\operatorname{num}_2$ are divisible by $3$, so there exists two integers $q_1$ and $q_2$ such that:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{num}_1 &= 3 q_1; \\
\operatorname{num}_2 &= 3 q_2.
\end{align}

Consider now the sum $\operatorname{num}_1 + \operatorname{num}_2$:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{num}_1 + \operatorname{num}_2 &= 3 q_1 + 3 q_2 \\
\operatorname{num}_1 + \operatorname{num}_2 & = 3(q_1 + q_2)
\end{align}

Let $Q = q_1 + q_2$. We have proven that $\operatorname{num}_1 + \operatorname{num}_2 = 3 Q$. Hence, $\operatorname{num}_1 + \operatorname{num}_2$ satisfies the definition of divisibility by $3$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The definition of divisibility is usually as follows: $a$ divides $b$ if there exists an integer $k$ such that $b = ak$.

And you are essentially showing that $k = q_1 + q_2$ for $b = \textbf{num}_1 + \textbf{num}_2$ and $a = 3$. The proof can be generalized to arbitrary divisor and difference quite easily.